# Replace parameters in a string and get array using typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a string like -

```
"{var1} apples, {var2} oranges are expensive".
```

and an object -

```
{ 
  var1 : <Link to="xyz">5</Link>,
  var2 : <Link to="pqr">6</Link>
}
```

I need help with writing a generic method in typescript which can take  string and object like above in input and based on keys of the object creates an array like -

```
[
<Link to="xyz">5</Link>,
" apples, ",
<Link to="pqr">6</Link>,
" oranges are expensive."
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const text: string = '{var1} apples, {var2} oranges are expensive';

const values = {
    var1: '<Link to="xyz"> 5 < /Link>',
    var2: '<Link to="pqr"> 6 < /Link>'
};

const tokens: string[] = text.split(/[{}]/).map(token => values[token] || token);

console.log(tokens);
```

Remove the leading empty string if necessary